# What kind of vulnerability is to do a scanf without specifying format string?

Tags: string, security, format, scanf

What kind of vulnerability is to do a scanf without specifying format string?

example: 
    `scanf(variable);`

Answer (score 3):

The vulnerabilities here are usually very technical in nature, but the issue is that the `scanf` function takes as parameters the address into which the values read should be written.  If you don't pass enough arguments to the function specifying where they should go, or you give the wrong type of arguments, then a malicious attacker can craft a format string for `scanf` such that the values read in are written into locations in memory that control sensitive information.  For example, the most common way in which functions are implemented work by storing somewhere on the stack the address of which instruction to execute next after the function returns.  If the attacker can somehow write data to this address, they can change where the function will return to.  Moreover, if the attacker can put binary data into memory from `scanf` (perhaps by feeding into `stdin` a bunch of data), they could in theory change the return address to jump into that binary data, hijacking the program and causing it to execute code of the attacker's choice.  This could be malicious, such as code to format the hard drive, or even worse could steal personal information, add a backdoor into the computer, etc.

For more information on how to execute generic attacks that work by writing data where it shouldn't go, the article ["Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit"](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) is a good reference.  It doesn't specifically address this type of issue, but the sorts of attacks described here can similarly be executed.

Hope this helps!